# Is running 2 instances of MATLAB safe?

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, matlab

Can I run another MATLAB while waiting for a long loop to finish?

I tried that before and it worked, but recently I tried again and found my PC (64-bit Windows 8.1 and MATLAB R2015b) frozen, with a bios-like window that complained about an unrecoverable error, so I had to reset it from the button.

Usually when I attempt to "abuse" the memory, MATLAB itself gives an error, but with 2 instances apparently something went wrong. Do they accidentally get allocated more memory than the system has? If so, -how- can I prevent this and run 2 instances safely?

I want to be sure that the PC won't froze because I'm using it remotely, so when it gets stuck, I have to go there (or ask someone) to reset it.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: How much ram are you using in your build?

Comment: there is 32GB RAM on the PC but I'm not sure if this is what you ask?

Comment: That's what I asked it should be good there is no error information it gives you when it freezes up in the event viewer?

Comment: Well I don't want to reproduce the error, but maybe Windows stored it somewhere? or MATLAB? not sure. I'm trying not to use too much memory but not sure if I accidentally did that. But still it's curious why MATLAB didn't give an out of memory error.

Comment: Open the event viewer with Windows Key and R then type in eventvwr and click run. And look under system events and see if there are any errors of why it shutdown. You can also check the application to see if any events were logged.